# Trying to import PersistentCookieJar library on Gradle project

Tags: gradle, cookies, okhttp

I'm doing a project with Gradle and I'm currently using `okhttp3` library in order to make requests to a webpage. A need a `cookie` handler so I'm trying to import [this library on GitHub](https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar). I don't know why the dependency is not recognized on IntelliJ.

This is my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

mainClassName = 'com.Main'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Gradle Jar File Example',
                'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'com.Main'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }    
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.franmontiel:PersistentCookieJar:v1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
}
```

EDIT: On Netbeans I got the same thing, the library isn't recognized.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This library is an Android Library (see the [library's gradle file](https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar/blob/master/okhttp3-persistent-cookiejar/build.gradle#L1) and the aar extension), you cannot use it as a Pure Java Library because it refers to several Android classpaths.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize that. Thank you